# select value into variable using input from form

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am having an issue selecting a value form my table into a variable in the PHP so that I can calculate the cost of something

here is the code I have so far I want to be able to select a "cost" value from the table `C_price` where the values of `I_type` and `a_type` match

**E.g.** the table structure looks like this

```
ID=1,A_type=line,I_type=Head,cost=5
```

if on the form i enter line and head
i need to be able to get the value 5 in to a venerable i can use in calculations and insert into another table AKA i need to get cost into a variable somehow

the following was my try and i need help im new at all this so please help

```
$E_C;
$T_cost = "1";
$date = date("d.m.y");
$name = $_POST["from"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$ref = $_POST["link"];
$i_type = $_POST["i_type"];
$a_type = $_POST["a_type"];
$extra = $_POST["extra"];
$des = $_POST["description"];
$BG = $_POST["BG"];
$bg_type = $_POST["BGtype"];
$msg = $_POST["message"];
$auto_reply = ("thanks for the email we will get back to you as soon as we can about the cost and   how you can pay");
$msg = wordwrap($msg, 70);


$host = "localhost";// hostname
$USER = "root";// username
$PASS = "Password";// password
$DBNAME = "andrea";// databace name
$tbl_name = "c_price";// table name

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $USER, $PASS, $DBNAME)or die("mySQL server connection failed");


$all = "SELECT cost FROM C_price WHERE a_type=$a_type,i_type=$i_type";  
$result = mysqli_query($con,$all) or die("Error getting total storse");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['cost'];
}

if ($a_type = 'waist' && $extra='Y') 
{
$E_C = $cost * .3;
}
elseif ($a_type = 'knee' && $extra='Y')
{
$E_C = $cost * .35; 
}
elseif ($a_type ='full' && $extra='Y')
{
$E_C = $cost * .4;
}
else 
{
$E_C = 0;
}

$T_cost = $cost + $E_C;

if ($BG = 'y')
{       
 $T_cost = $T_cost + 10;
}
```

Comment: Ps sorry for my spelling im dislexic and spell feneticaly

Comment: Mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` is wrong

Comment: `a_type=$a_type` should be `a_type='$a_type'`

Comment: your query is wrong this one $all = "SELECT cost FROM C_price WHERE a_type=$a_type,i_type=$i_type"; Change it to $all = "SELECT cost FROM C_price WHERE a_type='$a_type',and i_type='$i_type'"; And let us know what happned

Comment: Do you get a return from php. An error or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use mysqli and mysql at a same time.. Mysqli is a class... So first change that things...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $row['cost'];
}
   $news1 = mysqli_result($result, 0); // 0 is the index of the field, not the row
   echo $news1;
   echo $cost;`
```

Query should be like this...

```
$all = "SELECT cost FROM C_price WHERE a_type='$a_type'and i_type='$i_type'";
```

Comment: thanks i fixed that it seams to be die ing at  $result = mysqli_query($con,$all) or die("died at result");   even if its not dieing i still cant get the value of cost that i am pulling form the table into a Variable so i can use the value

Comment: i have removed the news1 line and below that dose nothing realy i am able to get a value if i add the actual values                            $all = "SELECT cost FROM C_price WHERE a_type='$a_type='line' i_type='Head'";                                                          the problem is i need to use values i am getting from the form

Answer (score 0):

**You cant mix mysql and mysqli**

change this line In the while loop and add for error mysqli_error

```
$news1 = mysql_result($result, 0);

$news1 = mysqli_result($result) or die(mysqli_error());
```

and your query is wrong as well **and** A_type is not same as A_type and same goes for I_type as well

```
$all = "SELECT cost FROM C_price WHERE a_type=$a_type,i_type=$i_type"; 
//Change it to 
$all = "SELECT cost FROM C_price WHERE A_type='$a_type'and I_type='$i_type'";
```

//and A_type is not same as a_type and same goes for I_type as well